# Kivy Carousel and Button Widgets

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Thanks to some friends on my last post I have a successfully working Kivy Carousel, now I am trying to add a "get started" type of button on the final page of the carousel that will take the user to the main app view when clicked.

I have a feeling that I need to implement logic such as "if the current picture is 'n' " to apply the button to the last screen only, but I am not sure how to make it work. I've looked all around for solutions but haven't found anything that relates to this particular concept..

This is my code for the carousel, thank you!!:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

class CarouselApp(App):

    def build(self):

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')

        #For each loop to take each image from directory and place in carousel
        for i in range(0, 3):
            src = "carousel/%s.png" % str(i)
            image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            carousel.add_widget(image)

        return carousel

CarouselApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last item of your carousel, instead of adding just an image, you must add a layout which will contain the image and the button:

**with a boxlayout**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CarouselApp(App):

    def build(self):

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')

        #For each loop to take each image from directory and place in carousel
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if i == 2:
                src = "carousel/%s.png" % str(i)
                button = Button(text='Get Started', on_press=self.get_started, size_hint_y=.1)
                image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True, size_hint_y=.9)
                layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
                layout.add_widget(image)
                layout.add_widget(button)
                carousel.add_widget(layout)
            else:
                src = "carousel/%s.png" % str(i)
                image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
                carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel

    def get_started(self, *args):
        print "let's start"

CarouselApp().run()
```

**with a floatlayout**

```
...
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

...

class CarouselApp(App):
    def build(self):
        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')
        #For each loop to take each image from directory and place in carousel
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if i == 2:
                src = "carousel/%s.png" % str(i)
                button = Button(text='Get Started', on_press=self.get_started, size_hint=(.5,.1), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .1})
                image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True, size_hint=(1, 1), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': 0})
                layout = FloatLayout()
                layout.add_widget(image)
                layout.add_widget(button)
                carousel.add_widget(layout)

...
```

Comment: OH! Nice! That makes perfect sense, thank you again!!